# SQLite Difference Between Dates

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to find the difference between these two dates and show it as a number of days, hours, minutes.

Here is how they are formatted now and below is what I've come up with but it doesnt seem to work...

5/18/17 4:57 PM

```
select *,strftime('%H:%M',CAST ((julianday('Completed Date') - julianday('Created Date')) AS REAL),'12:00') from report
```

Comment: I only see one date. Can you give some more? Can you explain the format (though it seems to be "month/day/year h:mm")? How would you want the output?

Answer (score 2):

`5/18/17 4:57 PM` is not a valid time string format in SQLite so it doesn't make sense to use `strftime` with such a format. You can only use `strftime` with a valid time string format such as `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

If you're looking to calculate the difference between `Created Date` and `Completed Date`, you would need to calculate the number of seconds between those two dates and use that to calculate the number of days, hours and minutes.

```
SELECT strftime('%s',"Completed Date") - strftime('%s', "Created Date") from report;
```

There are 86400 seconds in a day, 3600 seconds in an hour, and 60 seconds in a minute. You should be able to calculate the rest from here.

Comment: Does the wrong date format (as @CL has indicated in the comment) have an influence on your answer? In that light it seems that your answer might miss the point.

Comment: My answer is simply based on the `report` table having 2 datetime columns: `Created Date` and `Completed Date`. I don't understand what the wrong date format is about. The OP seems want to use `strftime('%H:%M')` to get the number of hours and minutes between two dates: Created and Completed. However, this would not work. I think the only way to find the difference between two dates is use of `strftime('%s')` to get the difference in seconds and use that value to calculate the difference in days, hours, minutes.

Comment: Did you try whether strftime works with `5/18/17 4:57 PM`, the example of a date given by OP? It does not with SQLite SQLite 3.18.0.

Comment: No, I didn't because strftime doesn't work with `5/18/17 4:57 PM`. It doesn't make sense to find the difference between dates with that particular format because that is an invalid date format in SQLite. If the OP wants to find the difference between dates (Created and Completed), then it can only be done by first calculating the difference in seconds from a valid datetime format such as YYYY-MM-DD for example. There are other valid datetime formats.

Comment: Providing the second part of a complete answer is OK. But you should explain that in your answer, i.e. that you left out the first, more difficult part, which adapts OPs unusual format to fit strftime. Alternatively, you can suggest to change his database structure to fit your solution. Either would avoid the impression that you did not really read the question and provided an answer which does not really solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot or want not change the date formats of your database structure. If that is possible definitly do so and have it much easier.
The output (see below) has a different date format, just for showing, keeping your own format in the output is of course possible.

I am using some common table expressions, to

- first split the dates into reusable part
- fix the individual formats
- arrange them into two dates suitable for strftime

There is some heavy string manipulation and a little daring "+12"/"+AM" in the midst of it.

Then I use kimbaudis proposal for calculation.
Credits to kimbaudi for going to seconds straight away,
I lost some time trying to play with julian days.

```
WITH parts -- splitting for reuse
(   wrongcomonth, 
    codayyear, wrongcohours, wrongcomins, wrongcom, 
    wrongcrmonth,  
    crdayyear, wrongcrhours, wrongcrmins, wrongcrm
) as
(select  
    substr(Completed_Date, instr(Completed_Date, '/'), -2) as wrongcomonth,
    substr(Completed_Date, instr(Completed_Date, ' '), -5) as codayyear,
    substr(Completed_Date, instr(Completed_Date, ':'),-2) as wrongcohours,
    substr(Completed_Date, instr(Completed_Date, ':')+1,2) as wrongcomins,
    substr(Completed_Date, instr(Completed_Date, 'M')+1,-2) as wrongcom,
    substr(Created_Date, instr(Created_Date, '/'), -2) as wrongcrmonth,
    substr(Created_Date, instr(Created_Date, ' '), -5) as crdayyear,
    substr(Created_Date, instr(Created_Date, ':'),-2) as wrongcrhours,
    substr(Created_Date, instr(Created_Date, ':')+1,2) as wrongcrmins,
    substr(Created_Date, instr(Created_Date, 'M')+1,-2) as wrongcrm
 from report),
 -- another "with"
     pretty -- fixing formats
(   coyear, comonth, coday, cohours, comins,
    cryear, crmonth, crday, crhours, crmins
) as
(select
    '20'||substr( codayyear, -2) as coyear,
    substr('0'||wrongcomonth, -2) as comonth,
    substr(replace(replace('_'||codayyear, '_/','_0'), '_', ''), 1,2) as coday,
    substr('0'||(wrongcohours+replace(wrongcom, 'PM', '12')), -2) as cohours,
    substr('0'||replace(wrongcomins, ' ', ''), -2, 2) as comins,
    '20'||substr( crdayyear, -2) as cryear,
    substr('0'||wrongcrmonth, -2) as crmonth,
    substr(replace(replace('_'||crdayyear, '_/','_0'), '_', ''), 1,2) as crday,
    substr('0'||(wrongcrhours+replace(wrongcrm, 'PM', '12')), -2) as crhours,
    substr('0'||replace(wrongcrmins, ' ', ''), -2, 2) as crmins
from parts),
-- another "with"
    times -- two, in correct format and order
(Completion_Time, Creation_Time
) as 
( select
    coyear||'-'||comonth||'-'||coday||' '||cohours||':'||comins as Completion_Time,
    cryear||'-'||crmonth||'-'||crday||' '||crhours||':'||crmins as Creation_Time
from pretty)
-- now the real thing, as proposed by kimbaudi
select  Creation_Time, Completion_Time, 
       ((strftime('%s', Completion_Time)-strftime('%s', Creation_Time))/(24*60*60))||'d '||
       (((strftime('%s', Completion_Time)-strftime('%s', Creation_Time))/(60*60))%24)||'h '||
       (((strftime('%s', Completion_Time)-strftime('%s', Creation_Time))/(60))%60)||'m'
from times;
```

MCVE `.dump`, with some different dates and a second line for testing:

```
-- cleanup 
drop table if exists report;

-- make playground
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE report ("Completed_Date" date, "Created_Date" date);
INSERT INTO report VALUES('5/8/17 10:57 AM','3/8/17 9:33 AM');
INSERT INTO report VALUES('12/31/16 4:1 PM','10/10/16 7:31 PM');
COMMIT;
```

Output (note the intentionally different dates for testing, in contrast to the date OP gave):

```
2017-03-08 09:33|2017-05-08 10:57|61d 1h 24m
2016-10-10 19:31|2016-12-31 16:01|81d 20h 30m
```